# My Dell Inspiron was beeping on startup,I removed battery and plugged it again.Now system is running smoothly

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, battery

**My laptop is dell inspiron 5558. Today when I pressed the power button, it started beeping(I can not say exactly how times it was beeping.I counted it was beeping 8 times)**

My Laptop is 3 years old, and it was first time when it  was beeping, I got scared as hell, I thought "It is beeping to explode" so I took out the battery

On the third attempt my laptop started with windows automatic repair screen, and it booted(started) smoothly

I ran the system diagnostics, it said that my battery is reaching to its end life.
I know that dust plays major role in system malfunction or it was just the battery issue or some other serious alarming bell

**Any and all help will be highly appreciated**

Comment: welcome to superuser, 3 beeps could mean a chip set problem(system board failure), but if it is not now beeping you could be ok. from http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln296283/how-to-use-and-troubleshoot-the-inspiron-15-5558-?lang=en . See number 12

Comment: @mic84 my laptop remains in my home always.As i have mentioned earlier, my laptop is 3 yrs old. Should i think about taking it to dell service centre for "dust cleaning".

Comment: you can buy a compressed air can and give it a shot yourself, but if at home all the time it should be ok and not in need of your local tech person.